# Can I use apoc.periodic.updates to return a query output?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a query that reads a set of ID's from a csv file, searches for those nodes in the database and writes the results to a csv. I'm trying to get this query to run as quickly as possible and was wondering if I could parallelise the read operation using `apoc.periodic.iterate`: 
http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/cypher-execution/commit-batching/

I've written a query that does what I need but really I just want to find out how to run this query as quickly as possible.

Here's the current, version of the query:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query('CALL apoc.load.csv(\'file:///edge.csv\') YIELD map as edge
MATCH (n:paper)
WHERE n.paper_id = edge.`From` OR n.paper_id = edge.`To`
RETURN n.paper_title',
'node.csv', {});
```

This query creates the resulting `node.csv` file that I want but as `edge.csv` grows in size the operation can slow down considerably.

What I was hoping to do was something like this:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
'LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM \'file:///edge.csv\' as row RETURN row',
'CALL apoc.export.csv.query(\'MATCH (n:paper) WHERE n.paper_id = row.`From` OR n.paper_id = row.`To` RETURN DISTINCT(n.paper_id) AS paper_id\', \'nodePar.csv\', {})'
, {batchSize:10, iterateList:true, parallel:true, failedParams:0})
;
```

This query will run but produce no output except for the following message:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| batches | total  | timeTaken | committedOperations | failedOperations | failedBatches | retries | errorMessages | batch                                                   | operations                                                | wasTerminated | failedParams |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 14463   | 144629 | 0         | 144629              | 0                | 0             | 0       | {}            | {total: 14463, committed: 14463, failed: 0, errors: {}} | {total: 144629, committed: 144629, failed: 0, errors: {}} | FALSE         | {}           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My main question is: can apoc.periodic.iterate be used in this way to accelerate this query and if so, how?

And then alternatively, is there any other way to speedup this query as the `edge.csv` file grows in size?

Comment: Is there an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:paper(paper_id)`?